# How do I derive that $(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})$ is $N(0,1)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distributed.
I have only learned the definition of normal distributions and I was told the fact that $(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})$ is $N(0,1)$.

But how can I get a proof of it? Would anyone help?

Comment: You can try to find its characteristic function which determines it uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

By finding mean and variance of $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ (which are completely determining for the distribution of normally distributed random variables).

For this use linearity of expectation and use equalities like: $$\mathsf{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\mathsf{Var}X$$

Comment: OK. I understand this for the mean. What about computation of the **variance**?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer really fills your needs then be so kind to accept it.

Comment: I've reread your hint, but I'm still lost.What is the R.V. about which we want to prove that it is $N(0,1)$ on the last line of your answer?

Comment: What is stated in the last line of my answer must be applied on $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\sigma^{-1}X-\sigma^{-1}\mu$. So for $a=\sigma^{-1}$ and $b=-\sigma^{-1}\mu$.